# Configure the Textile set in MarkItUp!

Tags: javascript, markitup

I am trying to configure the Textile set of MarkitUp! and facing the following issue:

I do not want h1. h2. h3. h4. h5. and h6. options in the editor. So i removed them from the default textile set options.

**Here is the default set:**

```
markupSet: [
        {name:'Heading 1', key:'1', openWith:'h1(!(([![Class]!]))!). ', placeHolder:'Your title here...' },
        {name:'Heading 2', key:'2', openWith:'h2(!(([![Class]!]))!). ', placeHolder:'Your title here...' },
        {name:'Heading 3', key:'3', openWith:'h3(!(([![Class]!]))!). ', placeHolder:'Your title here...' },
        {name:'Heading 4', key:'4', openWith:'h4(!(([![Class]!]))!). ', placeHolder:'Your title here...' },
        {name:'Heading 5', key:'5', openWith:'h5(!(([![Class]!]))!). ', placeHolder:'Your title here...' },
        {name:'Heading 6', key:'6', openWith:'h6(!(([![Class]!]))!). ', placeHolder:'Your title here...' },
        {name:'Paragraph', key:'P', openWith:'p(!(([![Class]!]))!). '},
        {separator:'---------------' },
        {name:'Bold', key:'B', closeWith:'*', openWith:'*'},
        {name:'Italic', key:'I', closeWith:'_', openWith:'_'},
        {name:'Stroke through', key:'S', closeWith:'-', openWith:'-'},
        {separator:'---------------' },
        {name:'Bulleted list', openWith:'(!(* |!|*)!)'},
        {name:'Numeric list', openWith:'(!(# |!|#)!)'}, 
        {separator:'---------------' },
        {name:'Picture', replaceWith:'![![Source:!:http://]!]([![Alternative text]!])!'}, 
        {name:'Link', openWith:'"', closeWith:'([![Title]!])":[![Link:!:http://]!]', placeHolder:'Your text to link here...' },
        {separator:'---------------' },
        {name:'Quotes', openWith:'bq(!(([![Class]!]))!). '},
        {name:'Code', openWith:'@', closeWith:'@'},
        {separator:'---------------' },
        {name:'Preview', call:'preview', className:'preview'}
    ]
```

**And here the modified one**

```
markupSet: [
        {name:'Bold', key:'B', closeWith:'*', openWith:'*'},
        {name:'Italic', key:'I', closeWith:'_', openWith:'_'},
        {name:'Stroke through', key:'S', closeWith:'-', openWith:'-'},
        {separator:'---------------' },
        {name:'Bulleted list', openWith:'(!(* |!|*)!)'},
        {name:'Numeric list', openWith:'(!(# |!|#)!)'}, 
        {separator:'---------------' },
        {name:'Picture', replaceWith:'![![Source:!:http://]!]([![Alternative text]!])!'}, 
        {name:'Link', openWith:'"', closeWith:'([![Title]!])":[![Link:!:http://]!]', placeHolder:'Your text to link here...' },
        {separator:'---------------' },
        {name:'Quotes', openWith:'bq(!(([![Class]!]))!). '},
        {name:'Code', openWith:'@', closeWith:'@'},
    ]
```

**The problem is now the action "Bold" is the first action in the editor but it is still showing  "H1" action thumbnail. How do I solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

you will also need to edit the according css file